# Save an Image object from my Webpage to File

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am using VB with ASP.  I have an ASP Image control that contains an image which in this case, is a static map brought in from Google Maps.  I would like to use VB code do download that image to an image (bmp, jpg, or anything).  The image resides in an asp:Image object on the client side.  Just need to download the image using code from the server side.  If necessary, I could use JS on the client side to do this.  In that case, I would still like to see if anyone out there knows how to do this.

Here is my javascript code to load the map displayed on the page to an asp:image object.  This part works great.  Just need to save the image as a file. There are predefined variables in prior code on the page that this function is using including "Map", "Map Options", "Bounds" and "Markers"

```
function Export() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

    //URL of Google Static Maps.
    var staticMapUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap";

    //Set the Google Map Center.
    staticMapUrl += "?center=" + mapOptions.center.G + "," + mapOptions.center.K;

    //Set the Google Map Size.
    staticMapUrl += "&size=220x350";

    //Set the Google Map Zoom.
    staticMapUrl += "&zoom=" + mapOptions.zoom;

    //Set the Google Map Type.
    staticMapUrl += "&maptype=" + mapOptions.mapTypeId;

    //Loop and add Markers.
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i];

        if (data.pointNumber !== null) {
            var labelNumber = data.pointNumber;
            var labelString = labelNumber.toString();
            var iconName = 'm' + labelString + '.png';
            var roundLat = data.latitude; // + .00003;
            var roundLon = data.longitude; // + .000005;

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(roundLat, roundLon);

            var image =
            {
                url: 'ImagesForPoints/' + iconName,
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 48), // scaled size
                //size: new google.maps.Size(53, 73),
                //origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), 
                //anchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 69)
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(19, 45)
            };


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                icon: image,

            });

            bounds.extend(marker.position);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);

        }
    }

    //Display the Image of Google Map.
    var imgMap = document.getElementById("imgMap");
    imgMap.src = staticMapUrl;
    imgMap.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: do you need only show the image in asp:image object?

Comment: Can you please add some sample code that demonstrates your problem and what you have so far? It would make it much clearer on which parts you're stuck on.

Comment: I can show the image already in an image object on the page.  All I want to do is save the image as a file somewhere. Alternatively, If I can get it as a filestream, I can do anything I need with it.  I just can't seem to do this.  I will post the code as to how it gets into a picture object on the screen. @toto

Comment: Can you provide me an example url where you get the image google map?

Comment: Here is my code. 
    `code`

Answer (score 0):

Since your using Google Maps Static API, which generates an image from a URL, your server side VB ASP.NET code only needs the URL that was used to generate the image, for it to be able to download it.

For example, the following URL from the Google Maps Static API will provide an image centered on Brooklyn Bridge, New York:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284
```

Your server side code will therefore need this URL to be able to download the exact same image. You could possibly get this URL to your server application in the possible following ways:

1. Send the URL back as HTML form submission (postback).
2. Write a web service that accepts a URL for download.

Since you appear to be using ASP.NET web forms, the first option would be your easiest choice for now. All you will need to do is to add a asp:HiddenField control to your page

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="MapURL" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

and then set the value of the field in you JavaScript export function:

```
var mapUrlField = document.getElementById('<%= MapURL.ClientID %>');
if (mapUrlField)
{
    mapUrlField.value = staticMapUrl;
}
```

And then on the on postback server-side, you can retrieve the URL from the hidden field and then use the WebClient to download the image.

```
Dim SaveFilePath as String = "c:\folder\mymap.png"
Dim Client as new WebClient
Client.DownloadFile(MapURL.Value, SaveFilePath )
Client.Dispose
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this tomorrow when I can get at my code. Note that I did  try an alert to view the URL coming from Google and it did not show the entire URL as I expected.  However, I will try this with your exact code tomorrow and see how this goes.

Comment: OK, I tried it and here is the funny thing.  The "staticMapUrl" passed by google does initially display the image perfectly on the page but when I capture the the string sent it is not correct.  In addition, on the website itself, the right click is disabled (not by me) and therefore no save as . . . option.  The URL that I am getting is:  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=undefined,undefined&size=220x350&zoom=19.38886&maptype=satellite.   The downloaded image is a map of the world with a msg:  Map error:  g.co/staticmaperror.  What do you think?

Comment: Well for starters, take a look at the URL you have provided. The center parameter has `undefined,undefined` in it which explains the `Map error: g.co/staticmaperror` message. This would suggest you have not setup `mapOptions.center.G` or `mapOptions.center.K` correctly. Have you even defined `mapOptions`? Use the browser's developer tools to debug your JavaScript code.